# Facebook ShareButton doesn't share until I press “back”

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have a menu button which opens an `AlertDialog`. The `AlertDialog` has my Facebook share button. The button works and opens the facebook share thing with "Write something..." and that all seems to work fine.

However,when I press **POST**, nothing is posted. I am taken to my news feed in the facebook app. Once I press back, THEN it posts to facebook. If I press **POST** (which takes me to my news feed) and kill the app, nothing is posted at all.

I would like my facebook share button to post as soon as **POST** is pressed, and then have the user taken back to my own app. Don't know whats wrong as this is what I would expect to happen in the first place

```
public void save(MenuItem item){

ShareButton fbShareButton = new ShareButton(Workout.this);
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
        .build();
fbShareButton.setShareContent(content);

AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Workout.this).create();
alertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.message_save));

alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, getString(R.string.option_save),
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                saveWorkout();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, getString(R.string.option_cancel),
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
alertDialog.setView(fbShareButton);
alertDialog.show();
}
```